# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_14 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (144, 11, 1756)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am running a CNN that check for images but does not classify. In fact, the output layer is a dense layer that have as argument the size of the images in the labels in 1d.

As shown below in the code, I am using model.fit_generator() instead of model.fit and when it comes to start training the model the following error comes up:

> "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_14 to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (144, 11, 1756)"

**Here attached is the summary of the model:**

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d_45 (Conv2D)           (None, 53, 1754, 8)       80

---

activation_57 (Activation)   (None, 53, 1754, 8)       0

---

max_pooling2d_43 (MaxPooling (None, 17, 584, 8)        0

---

conv2d_46 (Conv2D)           (None, 15, 582, 16)       1168

---

activation_58 (Activation)   (None, 15, 582, 16)       0

---

max_pooling2d_44 (MaxPooling (None, 5, 194, 16)        0

---

conv2d_47 (Conv2D)           (None, 3, 192, 32)        4640

---

activation_59 (Activation)   (None, 3, 192, 32)        0

---

max_pooling2d_45 (MaxPooling (None, 1, 64, 32)         0

---

activation_60 (Activation)   (None, 1, 64, 32)         0

---

flatten_15 (Flatten)         (None, 2048)              0

---

## dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 19316)             39578484

Total params: 39,584,372
Trainable params: 39,584,372
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

**Code:**

```
def generator(data_arr, batch_size = 12):

num = len(data_arr)

# Loop forever so the generator never terminates
while True: 

    #shuffle(data_arr)

    i = 0 

    for offset in range(0, num, batch_size):

        batch_samples = data_arr[offset:offset+batch_size]

        samples = []
        labels = []

        for i in range(0, offset+batch_size, 1): 

            for batch_sample in batch_samples:

                samples.append(data_arr[i][0])
                labels.append(data_arr[i][1])

            X_ = np.array(samples)
            Y_ = np.array(labels)

        i+= batch_size

        X_ = X_[:, :, :, newaxis]
        yield (X_, Y_)

# compile and train the model using the generator function
train_generator = generator(training_data, batch_size = 12)
validation_generator = generator(val_data, batch_size = 12)

run_opts = tf.RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom = True)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), input_shape = (55,1756,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3, 3)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3, 3)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3, 3)))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature 
vectors
model.add(Dense(19316))

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = 'adam',
          metrics = ['accuracy'],
          options = run_opts)

model.summary()

batch_size = 12
nb_epoch = 6

model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                steps_per_epoch = len(training_data) ,
                epochs = nb_epoch,
                validation_data = validation_generator,
                validation_steps = len(val_data))
```